# $\sigma$-finite projection von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Consider the following lemma from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebra II":

[image]

**Questions**:

(1) What is a $\sigma$-finite projection? I don't see a definition anywhere in either volume I or volume II.

I suspect it is a strong limit of a bounded increasing **sequence** of finite-rank operators in the von Neumann algebra?

(2) If $x \in M_0$, then why is $s_l(x) \in \Sigma$?

We know that $x= pyp$ where $p$ is $\sigma$-finite and $y \in M$. Write $p = \lim_n p_n$ where the $p_n's$ have finite rank. Then $x= \lim_n p_n y p_n$ strongly. Can I deduce from this that $s_l(x)$ is $\sigma$-finite? Or maybe a polar decomposition argument works here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A $\sigma$-finite projection in $M$ is a projection where each family  of pairwise orthogonal subprojections in $M$ is countable. When $M=B(H)$, this is equivalent with being  a sot limit of an increasing sequence of finite-rank projections.

A von Neumann algebra is $\sigma$-finite if the identity is. Takesaki defined this in II.3.18, where he also shows that for a von Neumann algebra being $\sigma$-finite is equivalent to having a faithful normal state, and also equivalent to having a countable separating set in $H$.

As for the second question, if $x=pyp$, then the range of $x$ is contained in $pH$, and thus $s_\ell(x)\leq p$. A subprojection of a $\sigma$-finite projection is $\sigma$-finite.

---

Suppose that $p,q$ are $\sigma$-finite. We want to show that $p\lor q$ is $\sigma$-finite. We think about it as above, in terms of $(p\lor q)M(p\lor q)$ being $\sigma$-finite. By Takesaki II.3.19 there exist countable separating sets $\{\xi_n\}$ for $pMp$ and $\{\eta_n\}$ for $qMq$. We want to show that $\{\xi_n\}\cup\{\eta_n\}$ is separating for $(p\lor q)M(p\lor q)$. Let $x\in (p\lor q)M(p\lor q)$  with $x\xi_n=x\eta_n=0$ for all $n$. We may assume without loss of generality that $p\xi_n=\xi_n$, $q\eta_n=\eta_n$, as these would still be separating. Note that $x^*x\xi_n=x^*x\eta_n=0$. So
$$
px^*xp\xi_n=px^{*}x\xi_n=0,\qquad qx^{*}xq\eta_n=qx^{*}x\eta_n=0
$$
for all $n$,
which gives $px^*xp=qx^*xq=0$.
If $\xi\in pH$, then $px^*xp\xi=0$, and thus $$0=\langle px^*xp\xi,\xi\rangle=\|x^{}p\xi\|^2=\|x^{}\xi\|^2,$$ so $x\xi=0$. Similarly, $x\eta=0$ if $\eta\in qH$. So $x=0$ on $pH\cup qH$, which means that $x=x(p\lor q)=0$. That is, the countable set $\{\xi_n\}\cup\{\eta_n\}$ is separating for $(p\lor q)M(p\lor q)$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the first sentence. Is countable here countably infinite? Then no projection in a finite-dimensional von Neumann algebra would be $\sigma$-finite. Or is it at most countable? Then every projection would be $\sigma$-finite as one can always write $p$ as a sum of one summand, namely itself. What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, I botched that. It should be fine now.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but it is also important that we can choose the finite rank projections in the von Neumann algebra itself etc

Comment: Good point. $ $

Comment: The point of $\sigma$-finite is that you cannot subdivide into uncountably many equivalent copies.

Comment: @MartinArgerami And are the following statements equivalent: $x$ is $\sigma$-finite (as in your definition) iff $x$ is the strong limit of an increasing sequence of finite projections (where a projection $p$ is called finite if $p \sim q \le p \implies q=p$)?

Comment: No, because (as you mentioned yourself, if I'm not wrong), it could be the case that $M$ has no finite projections at all. When $M$ has no summand of type III the answer is yes, because every projetion can be written as a (possibly infinite) sum of finite projections.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks! This makes sense.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Here is another Takesaki question if you have time/interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380621/decomposition-of-an-element-as-a-difference-of-positive-elements-in-the-definiti :)

Comment: I took a quick look and I don't immediately see it. Should be easy, but I don't know.

Comment: @Andromeda: why did you delete the post? Did you find the answer?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I posted on MO, and didn't want to crosspost. I can add it back here if you like.

Comment: No, fair enough. I just wanted to know what happened.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I started a bounty because I will yet again ask another follow-up question. What do you mean with equivalent subprojections? And why is the union of $\sigma$-finite projections again $\sigma$-finite? Do you have a reference to your definition of $\sigma$-finite. The closest thing I can find is exercise 7 chapter V.2 in Takesaki. 

As I understood it: the definition is the following: A projection $p\in M$ is called $\sigma$-finite if for every set $\{p_i\}_{i \in I}$ of pairwise orthogonal subprojections (i.e. $p_i \le p$) we have that $I$ is at most countable.

Comment: @MartinArgerami But now I see the word equivalent, so what does it mean...

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks for the edit! It has become much clearer now! Takesaki seems to be using that a countable supremum of $\sigma$-finite projections is again $\sigma$-finite. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer (I should have looked at Takesaki's definition to start with). The equivalence of the projections is not required. Now, you don't know equivalence of projections? And you are reading Tomita theory? Comparison of projections (Takesaki's chapter V) is the bread and butter of von Neumann algebras.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I do know equivalence of projections, but there are different equivalence relations that are relevant so was just clarifying what you meant. Although I have to admit that I skipped chapter V in Takesaki for the moment because it doesn't seem necessary to understand the basics of Tomita Takesaki theory (but correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @MartinArgerami It is also not clear to me why the supremum of a countable family of $\sigma$-finite projections is again $\sigma$-finite. Let us focus on the case of two elements: if $p,q$ are $\sigma$-finite, we want to show that $p \lor q$ is $\sigma$-finite. If $s \le p \lor q$, we want to relate $p$ to a subprojection of $p$ or $q$ so I can't think about anything else than considering $s \land p$ and $s \land q$, but this doesn't seem fruitful.

Comment: I have edited a cumbersome argument in. I did it for two, but it should be obvious that it works for countably many.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks! I'll see if it works, and then award the bounty once I can!

Comment: Keep the bounty for yourself, please. The points will do you way more good than to me, as you'll get quicker to being able to edit, close/reopen, seeing deleted questions/answer, etc.

Comment: @MartinArgerami It is already too late for that, but I don't mind rewarding someone who has helped me!